# What exactly does array of size N mean?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Sorry if this may be a stupid question, but in my Java book I read this sentence:

> Thus, when iterating over an array of size N, the enhanced for obtains
> the elements in the array in index order, from 0 to N-1.

I am reading about the for-each style for loop, and suddenly the book is talking about an array of size N and an index order of 0 to N-1. The book does not explain what N means, and strangely enough I googled a lot but could not find the answer. Maybe I am thinking to literally or too difficult. What does size N mean? Can someone give more information about this?

Comment: it's just a variable - think "algebra". N - generic unspecified (N)umber.

Comment: The N is just notation for the size (you could essentially replace N with 100 if that makes it easier)

Comment: N is just a variable. Size N where N = 10, or Size N where N = 57 etc.

Comment: this has nothing to do with Java, or arrays - you're having an issue with reading comprehension. throughout all of mathematics and programming, you'll find numbers represented and explained as x, y, or in this case, N.

Comment: I understand you, but due to specific reasons i sometimes have issues interpreting things the wrong way or too literally, so sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size *N* (or whatever it is named) is the number of items in your array or collection. Since indices are zero-based (as in other languages like C, Python, OCaml, ...), they run from 0 to *N* – 1.

As an example, if you have a 20-item array, *N* = 20 and the valid indices for this array run from 0 to 19.

Comment: Thanks, i thought that i was thinking too difficult and i was, thanks to all people who answered above as well :)

Answer (score 2):

An array is basically a fixed size list of elements. Here `N` refers to the size (or length) of the array. So it's the number of elements that it can store.

Elements in an array are obtained by using a zero-based index. That means the first element is at index 0, the second at index 1, and so on. Therefore, if the array has size `N`, the last element will be at index `N-1` (because it starts with `0`). Thus the index is in the interval `[0, N-1]`.

Here is the official [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for arrays explaining the basics in detail.

Answer (score 2):

> Java provides a data structure, the array, which stores a fixed-size
>   sequential collection of elements of the same type. An array is used
>   to store a collection of data, but it is often more useful to think of
>   an array as a collection of variables of the same type.

N is the number of items that you can store in your array.
See this link for more information:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm

Answer (score 1):

Hi Simon when an array has size N means that has no defined dimension that can be 1 to N.

When you don't know exactly wich is the size then in "math language" you just say N size. Be careful anyway that in Java an array can be initialized with size 0

Example:

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[];
```

Creates an empty array with length = 0.

I suggest you to have a look not only at your book but also at the [official java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) in order to have practical code examples

Answer (score 0):

For example, an array with 5 elements means N = 5.

Comment: N can't be negative in the context provided, so this answer is wrong.

Comment: Since when can an array have a negative amount of elements. I doubt the book will say array of size -3.

Comment: Well, your original answer was wrong (which can still be seen in the edit history).  I've adjusted my vote since this answer is now accurate.

Comment: But what I meant is any number as in the elements inside the array. But yeah, mybad, I guess I was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

N come from Natural number https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number but in java think of it as an int >= 0

Answer (score 0):

Array size of N means the size of that array is N. It is like saying...that container holds 5 gallons or 10 gallons etc. So for a array size of 5, N=5 and for a array size of 9, N=9 and so on.

If N=9, we can store 9 elements in that array and we will access these 9 elements starting from the index 0 all the way up to index 8. Remember that there is no 9th index here because we are starting from the 0th index and when we reach index 8, we will be accessing the 9th element.

This may seem a bit tough to digest for you at this stage of your programming career....you will become comfortable after a few months, after you have seen this a few more times.

Answer (score 0):

N is just a variable, it represents the amount of items could be in the array. The array could be 5 items, it could be 10 items, it could be 1000 items, it could be N items. Arrays begin from index 0, so the loop would run `0, 1, 2, 3 ... N - 3, N - 2, N - 1` times.